# Return list of posts back to a certain month in WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress, date, while-loop

I've got this typical query...

```
<ul>
<?php

    $back_dated = 8;

    $args = array (
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    global $post;
?>
    <li>
    <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

...but I need to be able to only return the post titles that are since the last month specified in the $back_dated variable.

So for example, if $back_dated = 8 then the list of posts returned should only be all posts since last August (because August is the 8th month).

Apologies if this has been asked before but I can't think of how to go about this and can't find an answer anywhere (even on SO).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use ***date query*** of wordpress available within **wp_query**.

For example:

`$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );`

**Return posts from January 1st to February 28th**

Reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query